# Worklight: Push notification will not work, because register/unregister to GCM service returned error AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, android-notifications

I have a Worklight app that uses push notifications. I use three Android devices (and two iOS ones) to test the notifications functionality:

1. A Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2.
2. A Galaxy XCover with Android 4.1.2.
3. A Galaxy Tab with Android 4.2.2.

Yesterday, all of a sudden, the XCover started to give the `Push notification will not work, because register/unregister to GCM service returned error AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error when trying to subscribe to notifications. The other two devices subscribe correctly. To be sure that it's the same version, I removed the app and installed it on all the three devices anew, to no avail.

```
26-10-2014 15:19:12:782 DEBUG   Clearing notification subscriptions.
26-10-2014 15:19:12:791 DEBUG   Clearing tag notification subscriptions.
26-10-2014 15:19:12:796 DEBUG   Send new server notification token id.
26-10-2014 15:19:12:798 DEBUG   Updating tag notification subscriptions.
26-10-2014 15:19:12:805 DEBUG   response [https://XXXXXXX] success: /*-secure-*/
26-10-2014 15:19:12:953 WARN    Push notification will not work, because register/unregister to GCM service returned error AUTHENTICATION_FAILED.
26-10-2014 15:19:12:979 DEBUG   Служба Push: неправильный пароль.. Notifying javascript about unsuccessful registration to the GCM service.
26-10-2014 15:19:13:80  ERROR   Cannot register for Google Cloud Messaging. Служба Push: неправильный пароль.
26-10-2014 15:19:14:959 DEBUG   Piggybacking event transmission
```

The couple of words in Russian read "Push service: wrong password". How is it possible that the same app works differently on three devices (whereas it used to work correctly on all the three)?

Worklight version 6.2.0.00-20140922-2259.

Comment: Andrey, did you manage to overcome this?

Comment: nope, still the same, with different Google keys (different apps), no idea what it could be

Comment: Did you try to reset the device?

Comment: Status of this question?

Answer (score 0):

My only thinking, because evidently the GCM account details are valid (working on 2 other devices), is that something went wrong in the device settings.

My suggestion is for you to reset the device to its factory setting, enable WiFI connection and try again to install the application and subscribe to notifications.